# Flink statsD integration

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, statsd

We are using `Flink 1.9.1` on `EMR 5.29` with multi-master mode enabled. We added the below configuration to the flink-conf.yaml file in conf folder and added the jar `flink-metrics-statsd-1.9.1.jar` to the flink/lib folder.

```
metrics.scope.jm: <host>.jobmanager
metrics.scope.jm.job: <host>.jobmanager.<job_name>
metrics.scope.tm: <host>.taskmanager.<tm_id>
metrics.scope.tm.job: <host>.taskmanager.<tm_id>.<job_name>
metrics.scope.task: <host>.taskmanager.<tm_id>.<job_name>.<task_name>.<subtask_index>
metrics.scope.operator: <host>.taskmanager.<tm_id>.<job_name>.<operator_name>.<subtask_index>

metrics.reporters: stsd
metrics.reporter.stsd.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.statsd.StatsDReporter
metrics.reporter.stsd.host: localhost
metrics.reporter.stsd.port: 8130
metrics.reporter.stsd.interval: 60 SECONDS
```

When we listen to the statsD port, we don't get any of the metrics. Is there anything that we are missing out? Is there a way to check if some parameter is not getting passed?

As suggested in one of the other answers, we tried giving the IP address of the master also. Does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue :
This should have been used:
`metrics.reporter.stsd.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.statsd.StatsDReporter`
Instead of:
`metrics.reporter.stsd.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.statsd.StatsDReporter`

Answer (score 0):

With Flink 1.9, you need to copy the jar file for the reporter into the lib directory of every machine in the cluster. So copy `flink-metrics-statsd-1.9.1.jar` from `opt` into `lib`.

If that doesn't fix it, check the logs -- there should be clues there.

Also, statsd normally uses port 8125. Are you sure it's listening on 8130?

Comment: thanks for the reply. We have another application(spark app) running on the same cluster which produces metrics to 8125. While eventually  we would use the same port, we wanted to test with a separate port and yes, the statsD config fie we used to start the console listener uses 8130. Also, is there a specific log file we would have to see? Job manager / task manager / yarn session / cli?

Comment: Check the job manager and task manager logs, since each of them has metrics to report.

Comment: thanks for the reply. A very stupid question. In AWS EMR, the child or instance nodes of a cluster don't have the flink installation. Only the master nodes do. Will this be an issue?

Comment: You need to have Flink on every node of the cluster. One to run as the master (job manager), and the others as workers (task managers).

Comment: We run the flink application on yarn in the detached mode. The contents of the lib folder in the master node gets loaded into classpath. Will we still need the installations in all the nodes? Becasue we are able to run our app in this setup.

Comment: I haven’t used EMR recently, so I can’t help with the details. But I do know you have to get the Flink statsd jar onto the classpath of all the nodes.